# How to create a parent account with option for multiple kid accounts under one parent using React?

Tags: java, reactjs, user-interface, user-experience

Fairly new programmer here. This is for school.

Tech Stack:
React
Spring Boot
Bootstrap
Log4
Java
Redux

Goal: Create a children's platform with a parent login. Parent account should be able to add kid profiles and access kid/multiple kid profiles without logging in to them individually. Kid profiles have no direct login outside of parent account. Kid profiles have limited site access to games, books, etc. Kid accounts can update limited profile info such as avatar, background color...

I am trying to learn how to do this and am unsure where to start with adding ability to put multi kid profiles under one adult profile. I might just be overthinking it but if anyone can point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

I am currently thinking of setting user types and then selecting a child profile sets the user type and user name. No idea where to go from there or how to add more than one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is pretty broad as asked. It seems like a one-to-many (adult-to-children) relationship where a user is either an adult or child. Adding multiple children is the same as adding multiple users except a child account is associated with their adult(s). Child accounts are accessible by their related adult(s). Privileges depend on adult/child status.